# Can't upload file to Google Drive via Google API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

When I try to upload file to Google Drive via Google API ( https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client ) I get error "Insufficient Permission" (reading files goes without any problem). Here is code sample:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

class GoogleConnector {
    private $client;
    public $report;

    function __construct($filesToSend, $backupFolder) {
        session_start();
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
        $this->client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
        //also try different variants of this:
        //$this->client->setScopes(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE)));

        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
            $folderId = "FolderIdFromGoogleDrive";

            $this->report = "";
            foreach ($filesToSend as $file) {
                $this->report .= $this->uploadFile($file, $folderID, $service);
            }
        }
        else {
            $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/googleapi/oauth2callback.php';
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }

    function uploadFile($fileName, $folderID, Google_Service_Drive $driveService) {
        $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                'name' => $fileName,
                'parents' => array($folderId)
        ));

        try {
            $content = file_get_contents($fileName);
            $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                    'data' => $content,
                    'mimeType' => 'application/x-gzip',
                    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                    'fields' => 'id'));
            return "File '$fileName' uploaded with id '$file->id'" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        catch (Exception $exc) {
            return "Error working with file '$fileName':" . $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Make sure that the user you are authenticating with has access to "FolderIdFromGoogleDrive

Comment: I use only one user and this user can create files inside "FolderIdFromGoogleDrive" via Google Drive website.

Comment: Apparently not if you are getting "Insufficient Permission".  try and do a file.list and make sure that the folder appears for the user.   If it appears then re-authenticate the user you must have authenticated once using a difference scope then the one you have posted here.

Comment: After uploading/removing some files via GoogleDrive website I get 401 "Invalid Credentials" in my script even with new created "OAuth 2.0 client ID" (i've downloaded it and updated client_secret.json on server)...

Comment: If you remove the credential file that you used to authenticate that user with then you will need to reauthetcate the user again the Access token you have will not work with a changed credentials

Comment: Thanks, after $this->client->revokeToken() I can see all content in my Google Drive. But problems with uploading files still exists - same "Insufficient Permission".

Comment: You are getting "Insufficient Permission" because the user does not have access to upload to that folder they may only have read permissions on it.  Do a file.list and check the permissions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have valid [Permissions for the file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource). You  must set the Permission role to "**owner**" and the role to **user** (as you are the one doing the uploading).

You can read more on this on [About Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions)